# Prevent HTML elements from being dragged/dropped

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I want to allow users to drag and drop a file for uploading. However, I do not want them to be able to drag and drop HTML images/links that are already on the page.

The catch: these images and links will be in a contentEditable container, so disabling dragging on them isn't desirable. The goal is to simply prevent the dropzone from lighting up when you drag a non-file over it.

For example:

```js
$(function() {
  
  $('#drop')
    .on('dragover', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#drop').addClass('active');
    })
    .on('dragleave drop', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#drop').removeClass('active');
    });
 
  
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#drop {
  border: dashed 3px #888;
  padding: 20px;
}

#drop.active {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

ol {
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="drop">
  DROP HERE
</div>

<ol>
  <li>Try dragging a file from your computer over it. This is acceptable.</li>
  <li>Now try dragging the image below image over it. This is not acceptable.</li>
  <li><a href="#">Try dragging this link over it, too! Also not acceptable.</a></li>
</ol>

<p>
   <img src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/408/287.jpg">
</p>
<p>
  The goal here is to prevent the dropzone from lighting up when you drag a non-file over it, but to not disable dragging entirely on these types of elements.
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I was looking for is to check for the data transfer type. If it contains `Files`, there is at least one file being dragged/dropped so we should activate and allow it. Otherwise, we can simply ignore the drag/drop actions.

```
$('#drop')
  .on('dragover', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Only activate dropzone if the user is dragging a file
    if( $.inArray('Files', event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.types) === -1 ) {
      return;
    }


    $('#drop').addClass('active');
  })
  .on('dragleave drop', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Only accept drops if the user is dropping a file
    if( $.inArray('Files', event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.types) === -1 ) {
      return;
    }

    $('#drop').removeClass('active');
  });
```

Comment: do you know if there is any way to prevent a majority of elements from being draggable in the first place? `draggable="false"` doesn't work. `user-select: none` doesn't work. `pointer-events:none` doesn't work. i can't find any info anywhere and i hate how you can select and drag anything on a page and often it will have ghost images, even though you probably won't be able to drop it anywhere anyways. any idea?